# How could I restore Rails core libraries to original status

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Currently, I've been playing about the core libraries like activesupport, activemodel by `gem open activesupport, ...`

However, it seems I modified some code mistakenly and not knowing where did I changed. How could I recover it to original status.

There is no git control under those folders `/Users/new_bike/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/railtie`, so I couldn't use `gco ./` to discard changes.

Any good alternative to fix it? Thanks

## Exception message after modifications

```
/Users/new_bike/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/railtie/configuration.rb:95:in `method_missing': undefined method `active_record' for #<Rails::Application::Configuration:0x007fe8c4064e60> (NoMethodError)
    from /private/tmp/YOURAPPNAME/config/environments/development.rb:23:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/new_bike/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/railtie.rb:210:in `instance_eval'
    from /Users/new_bike/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/railtie.rb:210:in `configure'
    from /private/tmp/YOURAPPNAME/config/environments/development.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/new_bike/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
    from /Users/new_bike/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind re-installing, you could perhaps do this then bundle again?

```
gem cleanup
gem cleanup --dryrun # This lists what will be deleted.
```